# Start webapp (EJB3+JSF2) with method from bean instead of page

Tags: jsf, ejb, entry-point

I'm pretty new to EJB + JSF and I'd like that my webapp's entry point would be a method of a bean instead of a view.

I mean, when someone types www.mypage.com I'd like it to go to a method of a bean and then be redirected to a view rather than go to any xhtml... how can I do this?

EDIT:

I need to load some data from the database to show it in the view that the user sees when he enters the app. It's not authentication, it's just that I need some data to be loaded before the user sees the website.

Comment: When you go into a view, the first thing executed is the constructor of the managed beans involved in the bean, then the `@PostConstruct` annotated method of the managed bean takes in action. There you can perform business logic like preparing the data to be displayed in the view. After that, the view will be rendered and will use the values of the attributes of the associated managed beans.

Comment: Your concrete functional requirement is unclear (i.e. what exactly is that method of a bean supposed to do?) but using a servlet filter is one way (especially if your concrete functional requirement is "authentication"). Please edit and improve your question to elaborate the concrete functional requirement.

Comment: I solved it annotating the method that loads the info with @PostConstruct, thanks Luiggi Mendoza!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annotating the method that loads the info with @PostConstruct gets the work done :D Thanks to [Luiggi Mendoza http://stackoverflow.com/users/1065197/luiggi-mendoza](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1065197/luiggi-mendoza)

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't provide an answer since on your last question looked like you didn't even review nor tried it =\.